# Does provisioning a Windows to go drive delete all data?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-to-go

I am thinking of creating a windows-to-go workspace, but need to know if creating the workspace will cause all data on the drive to be wiped or if it just creates a separate partition for the windows-to-go install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will delete all files. You'll get a warning when you run the **Windows To Go** creator tool.